# issue compiling 1.9.3-p327 with rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm

been driven mad with errors trying to get ruby to play nice on windows 7 64-bit. using rvm, i had no issue with 1.9.2 and 1.9.3-p194. but with 1.9.3-p327:

```
Error running `make`, please read [...]/make.log`
```

Here she is:

```
    CC = gcc
    LD = ld
    LDSHARED = gcc -shared 
    CFLAGS = -I/home/Cameron.Steele/.rvm/usr/include 
    XCFLAGS = -include ruby/config.h -include ruby/missing.h -DRUBY_EXPORT
    CPPFLAGS =   -I. -I.ext/include/i386-cygwin -I./include -I.
    DLDFLAGS = -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base,--enable-auto-import -Wl,--out-implib=libruby191.dll.a cygruby191.def  
    SOLIBS = cygruby191.res.o -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt  
linking miniruby.exe
file.o:file.c:(.text+0x434c): undefined reference to `_wcsicmp`
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:164: recipe for target `miniruby.exe' failed
make: *** [miniruby.exe] Error 1
```

not having a child... not as expensive as a computer, a lot less useful, and it's illegal to smash.

any help is preemptively much appreciated. i am already appreciating you.

Comment: It is extremely necessary you use cygwin instead of native Ruby? cygwin is not one of Ruby supported platforms (no maintainer) and RubyInstaller already provides native binaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see:  https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7415#change-33382

The Ruby folks recognize this as a bug and have the issue in the Backport93 list.  It is scheduled to be repaired.